# Entity Framework создает свою связующую таблицу вместе с моей моделью?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имею следующие модели:

```
public class Order
{
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal? Cost { get; set; }
    public string Statement { get; set; }
    public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> DatePayment { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

И Связующую:

```
public class OrderProducts
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]

    public int Product_Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]

    public int Order_Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Product_Id")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Order_Id")]
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда создаю первую миграцию, то EF предлагает мне создать 2 связующие таблицы(c остальными все хорошо):

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.OrderProducts",
            c => new
                {
                    Product_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Order_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Count = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Product_Id, t.Order_Id })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Orders", t => t.Order_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Products", t => t.Product_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Product_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Order_Id);

CreateTable(
            "dbo.ProductOrders",
            c => new
                {
                    Product_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Order_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Product_Id, t.Order_Id })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Products", t => t.Product_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Orders", t => t.Order_Id, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Product_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Order_Id);
```

Пробовал и через Fluent Api сделать связи, и через аннотации, результат один.

Что я делаю не так? Все было хорошо, но  возникла потребность в дополнительном столбце Count и я столкнулся вот с такой проблемой.

Comment: Ну так просто не создавайте промежуточную таблицу вручную, зачем она вам? Пусть EF создаст ее сам за кулисами. Вы же просто пользуйтесь навигационными свойствами

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я ей и пользовался, но как тогда мне в нее добавить Count, если она за кулисами?

Comment: А что такое Count? Думаю, вы действуете неправильно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Это количество продукта в заказе. С клиента приходит корзина, в которой пользователь заказал, например, 10 ручек. Этот столбик для этого. Order_id - какой заказ, Product_Id - товар, Count - количество этого товара.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связь многие-ко-многим реализуется посредством создания промежуточной таблицы, но она создается EF самостоятельно "за кулисами".

Я думаю, вы спроектировали модель не совсем правильно. У вас есть классы Продукт и Заказ. Но заказ ведь содержит не просто товары, а некие **товарные позиции**, которые в себе уже содержат информацию о товаре, его количестве и цене (ваше решение, например, не позволяет безболезненно изменить стоимость товара - она повлияет на все заказы, в том числе и совершенные раньше).

Поэтому я бы создал отдельно класс Товарная позиция, а в классе Заказ создал бы коллекцию Товарных позиций. Ну а из товара вообще никаких ссылок на заказы не должно быть по смыслу.

Comment: Действительно, ваше решение логично. Попробую переделать, спасибо!